# Testing Vuejs EventBus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have been trying to figure this out for some time already, but I can not make it work! I found some examples on internet, but nothing solves it, every time I run my test I get:

```
 Expected number of calls: 1
 Received number of calls: 0

> 186 |        expect(wrapper.vm.EventBus.$on).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

The component looks like this:

```
import {EventBus} from 'eventbus'
export default{
    data(){ return {}},
    mounted(){
        EventBus.$on('saveTerminal', function(){
             this.someOtherFunction()        
        })
    }
}
```

Event Bus file looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

The Test looks like this:

```
    const GlobalPlugins = {
         install(v) {
            v.prototype.EventBus = new Vue();
         },
     };
    //Vue.prototype.EventBus = new Vue(); <-- I tried this also, didn't do anything
    
    // Mounting component
    const $t = () => {}
    const params = { localVue, store, router,
        propsData: {
            isEdit: false
        },
        data(){
            return {
                loading: false,
                tabIndex: 1
            };
        },
        mocks:{
            $t,
            EventBus: {
                $on: jest.fn(),
                $off: jest.fn(),
                $emit: jest.fn()
            }
        },
     }
    
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, params)
   describe('My component', () => { 
       it('Event bus', () => {
           wrapper.vm.EventBus.$emit('saveTerminal');
    
           expect(wrapper.vm.EventBus.$on).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(wrapper.vm.EventBus.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('saveTerminal', expect.any(Function))
       });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jest.mock()` to mock the `EventBus` module](https://jestjs.io/docs/bypassing-module-mocks). Your test would `require()` the module to access the mock, and then verify its `$on` was called:

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

jest.mock('@/utils/EventBus')

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it(`listens to 'saveTerminal' upon mounting`, async () => {
    const { EventBus } = require('@/utils/EventBus')
    shallowMount(MyComponent)
    expect(EventBus.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('saveTerminal', expect.any(Function))
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-mock-imported-eventbus-jest?file=tests%2Funit%2FMyComponent.spec.ts)

Comment: this looked very promising, I copied your example, and I am getting expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
Expected: "saveTerminal", Any<Function>
Number of calls: 0

Comment: Yes I copied your example from the demo. I don't have a link to the problem at this stage. I am going to try to create one, I have never done for a project with jest. But do you think this is because of the environment where I am running it?

Comment: Not sure. I'd have to see your code. Just fork my demo, and update the fork to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, not sure If I can reproduce the problem in there, I have copied some of the settings files, I am getting weird errors https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-mock-imported-eventbus-jest-m7bx6w?file=package.json

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really offer much help without a reproduction.

Comment: tx I will see how I can do that. Your example made me think that something wrong is with my environment or a setting